# PHP search results when page is return

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search

I'm currently display the search results in the same page (index.php), in the parameters of URL I just put **index.php?type=search**

```
<form method='POST' action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?type=search'>
```

So, in the **index.php** I check if it's search or not:

```
if(!isset($_GET['type'])) {
    echo $load->common();
}else{
    if($_GET['type'] == 'search'){
        if(isset($_POST['search-what-box'])){
            echo $load->search($_POST['search-what-box'], $_POST['search-where-box'], null);
        }else{
            echo $load->common();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I make several verifications. But imagine that people enter in another url (of my page), like **list.php?id=33** and then they click on Back button of the browser..the browser will display (with this code) the results of `$load->common()` and not the `$load->search()`, because the `$_POST['search-what-box']` wasn't pressed (the form wasn't submited).

How can I show the results of search instead of common results after people click on back button of browser? Should I save the information (after submiting the form) in javascript and then load it again by jQuery or there's a better approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, even if the user clicks on the 'Back' button, the URL will remain the same (along with the GET variable).

Comment: @user2513523 you're right. The problem is that on the URL I only display: index.php?type=search..I don't put what the user searched on the URL.

Comment: Got what you mean, sorry missed the POST condition.

Comment: When people hit the back button the browser should show them the result of the POST or a "Confirm form resubmission" dialog, no?

Answer (score 2):

Unrelated to your question, but you mix `$_GET['type']` and `$_POST['search-what-box']`. While technically possible, you should use either `$_GET` or `$_POST`.

To solve the "Back button problem", you might use the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) idiom.

Comment: The $_GET is used because I redirect the page to the same page. So, the URL changes with PHP_SELF, that's why I'm using $_GET. The $_POST is just to get the information.

Comment: @user3065191 Ok, now I get it. I didn't look close enough the first time.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should design your website that flexible that the back button is not nesessary at all.

But if you really want to save your last search result you can save it in $_SESSION for example on the server's side.

Comment: I'm talking about the backbutton of the browsers, like chrome. You can back for your previous page. About the $_SESSION, I think it's a good possibility..and I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

you may use a JQuery Ajax call [see here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

if click back the Get and Post data information are the previous ones in this case, ajax then uses that information to render the page

Answer (score 0):

First question is what the behavior of *browsers*. As far as I can see, browsers are not loading the page anew when you pressing back - they show you the page itself as the server sent them before (with the post data).

Comment: The browser when I press back is displaying the common results (which is fair) because I have a condition in my code verifying if $_POST was submited..which wasn't when you press back.

Comment: I'm not sure, just asking: are browsers bothers at all to make new request for the sever when you're pressing back, or they show you just a cached one from their own memory? In this case your code is not matter because the browser never ask for the page again.

Comment: They make a new request (for what I've tested). I've come to a solution. I'll post it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the search query part of the URL? Use `_GET` instead, this is what Google.com does. That way I could paste out the URL and give it to someone and it'd view the results.

Comment: Well, that's actually true. With only index.php?type=search people could not pass between them the URL with results..probably the best will be index.php?type=search&what=testing..I think it's better than sessions just because of sharing url.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, and it's a little less overhead for your server. Symantically it also makes sense since you're `GET`ting information from your server, to use `GET` vars

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, with all your answers and help **I solved my problem**.

```
$url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
// urldecode = some special characters might be in the query

$parse = parse_url($url);
// documentation: http://pt1.php.net/parse_url

if(isset($parse['query'])){
    $split = $parse['query'];
    parse_str($split);

    // documentation: http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

    if(isset($what)){
        echo $load->search($what, $where);
    }else{
        echo $load->common();
    }
}else{
    echo $load->common();
}
```

If anyone think there's a better approach, let me know.

Thanks